# what are the various fields in which circle is treated as infinite sided regular polygon?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, circles

What are the various fields in which circle is treated as infinite sided regular polygon?
What I actually mean is ,
"can u suggest me some applications where circle is treated as infinite sided polygon."
for example parallax method .

Comment: I can't really think of any off-hand, but that's maybe a failure of the imagination. From my perspective, I would want to take care in thinking of the circle as an infinite-sided polygon. It is *qualitatively* different from any regular polygon because its symmetries include infinite cyclic subgroups.

Comment: @Neal - There are a lot of infinities. I think the difference is that the "infinite-sided polygon" will have a countably infinite natural number of sides/vertices (a polygon can't have 2.5 sides, much less $\pi$ sides), while a circle has an *uncountably* infinite number of points at radius *r* from an origin *O*.

Answer (score 2):

Beginning with Archimedes there are many instances where a circle is considered as *limiting figure* for a sequence $(P_n)_{n\geq3}$ of regular polygons.

Usually a polygon has finitely many vertices $v_k$ and edges $e_k$ alternating as $$v_0,\  e_1,\ v_1,\ e_2,\ \ldots,\ v_{n-1},\ e_n, \ v_n=v_0\ .$$
There might even be polygons with countably many  vertices and edges, e.g., the convex hull of the set
$$\bigl\{1,-i,-1,i, e^{i\pi /3},e^{i\pi /4},e^{i\pi /5},\ldots\bigr\}\subset{\mathbb C}\ .$$
Now a circle has uncountably many points, and between any two of them there are infinitely many more. Therefore the idea of  consecutive points between which  edges might be inserted makes no sense.