# What are the applications?

Tags: calculus, geometry, circles, polygons

How can I show that a sequence of regular polygons with n sides becomes more and more like a circle as n→∞?
In which fields this concept is applied?

Comment: See this : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466762/why-is-pi-r2-the-surface-of-a-circle

Comment: It's not very polite to the people who already answered this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535659/what-are-the-various-fields-in-which-circle-is-treated-as-infinite-sided-regular to ignore those answers and ask again.

Comment: The OP certainly knows about the answers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/478005/73025) as he tried to post a question about applications there as an answer. That said, it is unclear what is he asking about. Vote to close.

Answer (score 0):

[Approximating the area and perimeter of a circle](http://www.math.psu.edu/courses/maserick/circle/circleapplet.html).

The idea is that as the approximating shape gets closer to the circle,  the area and perimeter of the shape get closer to the circle's area and perimeter.